# Populating HTML table with Javascript and retaining CSS style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, html-table

So far I have the code below working. My only problem is the associated styles of the HTML table are not being applied when the table is inserted into its parent div. What is the best way to resolve this? I am using jQuery in tandem with jQuery mobile.

```
var tableBase = '<table data-role="table" id="score-table" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" class="ui-responsive table-stroke ui-table ui-table-reflow"><thead><tr><th data-priority="1">Event</th><th data-priority="2">Score</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
function buildTable(data) {
     var tableCopy = tableBase;
     data.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
         tableCopy = tableCopy + '<tr><td>' + element.event + '</td><td>'
            + element.points + '<td></tr>';
      });
tableCopy = tableCopy + '</tbody></table>';
return tableCopy;
}
```

I then have have a `#('#targetDiv').html(buildTable(myData))` that inserts the tables html into its div. Everything works except the styles are not applied. I am using the responsive/reflow table from jQuery mobile.

Comment: element.points + '<td></tr>';  There is a syntax error. The td is not closed correctly : element.points + '</td></tr>';

Comment: Inline CSS is not good practice. Try defining the CSS styling in Javascript or in the style tags of the document's head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have too rerun the plugin for the table after it's inserted to the DOM: 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html

```
// Pages are lazily enhanced. We call page() on the page
// element to make sure it is always enhanced before we
// attempt to enhance the listview markup we just injected.
// Subsequent calls to page() are ignored since a page/widget
// can only be enhanced once.
$page.page();

// Enhance the listview we just injected.
$content.find( ":jqmData(role=listview)" ).listview();
```

Comment: I scrapped my responsive for a list view. This worked as an excellent alternative solution. 
I also used jquery to apply the proper styles AFTER I inserted the list code but before the enhancement.